# Relation between Aitchison Distance on a Simplex and Geodesic distance on the multinomial manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, st.statistics, information-geometry

I am trying to understand the difference/relation between the Aitchison distance on a simplex 
$$\left[ \sum^D_{k=1} (\log{\frac{x_{ik}}{g(\mathbf{x}_i)}} - \log{\frac{x_{jk}}{g(\mathbf{x}_j)}})^2 \right]^{1/2}$$

and the distance you get from computing the geodesic distance between two points on the multinomial manifold (also a simplex) under the Fisher information metric
$$arccos\left(\sum^D_{k=1}\sqrt{x_{ik}}\sqrt{x_{jk}}\right)$$ which also seems to be related to the Bhattacharyya distance.

I am particularly confused because in reading on the Aitchison distance I see statements of the form: "The simplex $S^D$ has the structure of a Euclidean space." Whereas the [multinomial manifold](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.358.1338) sounds like it is a curved space.

How do I understand these differences?

[See here for an overview of Difference Measures for Compositional Data](http://ima.udg.edu/~barcelo/index_archivos/Measures_of_difference__Clustering.pdf)

[See here for derivation of Geodesic distance under Fisher information Metric on Simplex](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.358.1338)

Comment: Interesting question, but would you mind to explain your choice of coordonates in the formulas? Should I replace $x_{ik}$ by $x_k$ and $x_{jk}$ by $y_k$, and are we considering the $D$-simplex as the convex hull of $e_0, \dots, e_D$ in $\mathbb R^{D+1}$ (so your sums start with $k=0$)?

Comment: To be honest I just took it right out of this reference: http://ima.udg.edu/~barcelo/index_archivos/Measures_of_difference__Clustering.pdf. I am perfectly happy saying the sums start from 1 or 0. I'm sorry I think I am probably missing the crux of your comment.